Prevent sudo ignore password policies
This is my /etc/pam.d/common-password file on ubuntu 22.04
password        requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3 minlen=12
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass yescrypt
password        sufficient                      pam_sss.so use_authtok
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
password        required                        pam_permit.so
password        optional                       pam_gnome_keyring.so

I have user called "student" and when I run
passwd student

and try write new password that contain only 1 symbol, the password policy works and I can not do it
but when I run
 sudo passwd student

I can write only one symbol and my password will change
How to prevent sudo command to ignore password policy?
